# Windows 10 hotspot not working

Tags: networking, windows-10, hotspot

Let me first explain the circumstances.

About a year ago, I started using [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/) to create a wifi hotspot from my Windows 8.1 Laptop. Then I bought a new computer with Windows 10, where I successfully used connectify as well (I actually bought an extra Wifi card to achieve this). Then, maybe half a year ago, I discovered the Windows 10 Wifi hotspot function. I wanted to try it, so I turned it on, but I didn't like it as much as the connectify hotspot (e.g. because it shuts itself down), so I wanted to use connectify again. There however I got the following error message: *A Wi-Fi driver bug prevented the hotspot from starting. Please restart your computer and try again.* I actually tried restarting, which didn't help, and even wrote to the support, which answered that my wireless adaper's driver doesn't work with a wifi hotspot (which doesn't make sense as it worked before). If you want to, I'll attach the log files or anything, but this actually isn't the problem. I then decided to use the built in Windows 10 hotspot, which worked pretty well for some time, until maybe a month ago.

If I click onto the mobile hotspot function

[image: Mobile hotspot button]

it's stuck on *Connecting*. Later it appears to be off again, but if I try to start it now, nothing happens. If I try to turn the mobile hotspot on over the Settings, it's always on the state off (even if I tried to start it over the menu you can see in the picture above). If I try to start it here, it's stuck on *Applying settings*, but if I restart the settings application, it's on the state *Off* again. Interesting is now, that the hotspot is actually turned on (I can detect it with my mobile phone), but I can't connect to it (it won't give me an IP address). If I select a static IP setting and assign my phone an IP address for myself (192.168.137.5 with the default Gateway 192.168.137.1, which seems to be my computer, which I know because of the message Windows 10 gave me and which you can see further below) it will connect, but tell me that I this network doesn't have an internet connection, which is correct.

If I go to *Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections*, go to the properties of my Ethernet adapter, click on *Sharing*, both options (*Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection* and *Allow other network users to control or disable the shared Internet connection*) are turned on. However, the *Home networking connection* isn't selected. If I select something (e.g. my opened Wifi hotspot, which appears under the name of *Local Area Connection* 11*) and click OK, I receive the following message:

> When Internet Connection Sharing is enabled, your LAN adapter will be
>   set to use IP address 192.168.137.1. Your computer may lose
>   connectivity with other computers on your network. If these other
>   computers have static IP addresses, you should set them to obtain
>   their IP addresses automatically. Are you sure that you want to enable
>   Internet Connection Sharing?

When I click OK, the property window of my ethernet adapter stops responding for quite a long time, finally showing the message:

> An error occurred while Internet Connection Sharing was being disabled. There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.

I searched for this message on Google but didn't get any results.

I'm using Windows 10 Pro, Version 1709, OS Build 16299.19. I couldn't find anything interesting in the event viewer of Windows and already tried reinstalling the driver of my Wifi card.

Does anybody have a solution to this, or is it just a bug of Windows 10?

---

**EDIT**: It's once again not working. After I applied Tiwaris solution it worked for a week or so but now I'm having a pretty similiar issue. Now however, if I try to turn it on over the settings, I get the helpful error message "We can't set up mobile hotspot." after some while. I really don't want to reset my firewall every week, so does anyone have an idea of how to solve this or is experiencing the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading my laptop to Windows 10 Fall Creators Update 1703.
After a day of trys I have solved the problem by resetting the Windows Defender Firewall to the default settings.
To do this open
Settings -> Update and Security -> Windows Defender -> Open Windows Defender Security Center -> Firewall and Network Protection -> Restore Firewall default settings

Comment: Are you sure this works? And why did this answer get a downvote?

Comment: It works again, though it's not a very good solution, as it resetted all firewall configurations.

Comment: It's once again not working anymore - have a look on my question to get more details.

Comment: This didn't work for me.